# Tab controller being pushed by the the navigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to iphone development. I'm trying to implement a tab view controller and a navigation controller. The problem that I'm having is that the navigation controller is pushing the tab bar view. How can you make the navigation controller slide without pushing the tab bar view? Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the code that you're using to set up the tabbar and navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your code, however to achieve the effect you are after you need to create an array of Navigation controllers and add them to your TabBar:

```
myTabBarController.viewControllers = navigationControllerArray;
```

When you push a view controller the tabBar will remain in place.  Equally if you touch a tab then you will switch to the view controller in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should not push a tabbar view in navigation controller. Rather you should create a tab bar controller and then add navigation controller to it. Doing so will just slide navigation controller not tab bar. You can refer to iPhone SDK documentation for more information.